# Installing python kats on macos m1

Tags: python, pipenv

I aim to use [python kats](https://facebookresearch.github.io/Kats/) library to do some time series analysis. I can not get it to install using python 3.11 on my Mac.

Basic machine info:
M1 Macbook Pro
Python Version: 3.11

The process for installation:

```
➜  workspace mkdir kats-experiment
➜  workspace cd !$
➜  workspace cd kats-experiment
➜  kats-experiment pipenv install --python  3.11
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/james/workspace/kats-experiment/Pipfile
Using /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 (3.11.6) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.11.6.final.0-64 in 1716ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/james/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.2.1, setuptools==68.2.2, wheel==0.41.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (102cb99fcf0bcc5f47dd749d9fbb3e31d68924b88460c0d504129ac825be2142)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (be2142)...
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
➜  kats-experiment pipenv install kats
Installing kats...
Resolving kats...
Added kats to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (be2142) out of date, updating to (4c5c22)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠋ Locking...
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting kats (from -r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached kats-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (612 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting attrs>=21.2.0 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting deprecated>=1.2.12 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Obtaining dependency information for deprecated>=1.2.12 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/8d/778b7d51b981a96554f29136cd59ca7880bf58094338085bcf2a979a0e6a/Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib>=2.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/f3/fb27b3b902fc759bbca3f9d0336c48069c3022e57552c4b0095d997c7ea8/matplotlib-3.8.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached matplotlib-3.8.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting numpy<1.22,>=1.21 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached numpy-1.21.1.zip (10.3 MB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting pandas<=1.3.5,>=1.0.4 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.0 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting pystan==2.19.1.1 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached pystan-2.19.1.1.tar.gz (16.2 MB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting fbprophet==0.7.1 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting scikit-learn>=0.24.2 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Obtaining dependency information for scikit-learn>=0.24.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/c6/2e91eefb757822e70d351e02cc38d07c137212ae7c41ac12746415b4860a/scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.operations.prepare:Collecting scipy<1.8.0 (from kats->-r /var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pipenv-s569uhlm-requirements/pipenv-zqq0oo5_-constraints.txt (line 2))
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.network.download:Using cached scipy-1.6.1.tar.gz (27.3 MB)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.cli.spinners:Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 646, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 613, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 593, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 845, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 618, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 444, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 648, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 786, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pipenv/2023.8.26/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 655, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

This error is not very descriptive

If, as suggested, I run:

```
pipenv run pip install kats
```

The output is:

```
Collecting kats
  Using cached kats-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (612 kB)
Collecting attrs>=21.2.0 (from kats)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2.12 (from kats)
  Obtaining dependency information for deprecated>=1.2.12 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/8d/778b7d51b981a96554f29136cd59ca7880bf58094338085bcf2a979a0e6a/Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0 (from kats)
  Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib>=2.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/f3/fb27b3b902fc759bbca3f9d0336c48069c3022e57552c4b0095d997c7ea8/matplotlib-3.8.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.22,>=1.21 (from kats)
  Using cached numpy-1.21.1.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pandas<=1.3.5,>=1.0.4 (from kats)
  Using cached pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.0 (from kats)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pystan==2.19.1.1 (from kats)
  Using cached pystan-2.19.1.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl
Collecting fbprophet==0.7.1 (from kats)
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.24.2 (from kats)
  Obtaining dependency information for scikit-learn>=0.24.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/c6/2e91eefb757822e70d351e02cc38d07c137212ae7c41ac12746415b4860a/scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting scipy<1.8.0 (from kats)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.1.tar.gz (27.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [123 lines of output]
      setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-1apq9j1t'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      setup.py:563: DeprecationWarning:

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      INFO: lapack_opt_info:
      INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
      INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_ssl2_info:
      INFO:   libraries fjlapackexsve not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: flame_info:
      INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: accelerate_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1974: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO: lapack_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1974: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/james/.virtualenvs/kats-experiment-AHXRJQ7w/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 254, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 588, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 584, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/private/var/folders/gn/cnpn1v5n2f76fkstdxc6vyww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nu_ho94k/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 136, in setup
          config = configuration()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "setup.py", line 499, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError(msg)
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
      To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
      See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
      https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried installing openblas with

```
brew install openblas
```

This still errors.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

kats seems to officially only be supported for Python 3.7 and 3.8: https://pypi.org/project/kats/